# Heroku: user of both herokuapp.com and custom domain SSL at the same time

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns

I am now managing a web service site as herokuapp.com domain name with Piggyback SSL.
And I am planning to migrate from the herokuapp domain to custom domain with custom SSL.

Here is a question,
Is it possible to use herokuapp.com domain name even after we set up custom domain SSL and get a SSL endpoint as herokussl.com domain?
Does anyone have experience of using both domains?

Thanks,

Masahiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work fine.

Because you're only pointing your custom DNS entry at the SSL endpoint eg tokyo-2121.herokussl.com then the original herokuapp.com and ssl will still be accessible provided you're not doing any kind of domain checking and redirection in your code.

Comment: Thanks, John.
We'll set up a custom domain SSL.